# Взаимодействие C# и C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++builder

Есть dll-ка написанная на C# и есть программа написанная на Borland С++ которая жаждет использовать методы реализованные в dll-ке.

Вопрос: Как это взаимодействие лучше организовать если:

- dll-ка при необходимости (если такое изменение понадобится для организации взаимодействия с С++) может превратиться в exe или даже службу
- некоторые методы реализованные в dll в силу особенностей .Net ощутимо долго отрабатывают при первом вызове. Да и dll-ке желательно проводить
  некоторую подготовительную работу (обновлять используемые файлы и
  тп.) и лучше если она будет делать это один раз за весь цикл работы
  вызывающей программы.
- dllка полностью в моей власти могу изменять её код как мне угодно. программа на C++ вне моей власти. Максимум что мне доступно-объяснить разработчикам как использовать мою dllку.
- Желательна схема не требующая дополнительных действий (перерегистрация/перезапись реестра/переустановка компонентов и т.п.) при обновлении dllки.
- производительность критична.

PS: Отдельное спасибо за пример реализации такого взаимодействия на Builder C++

Comment: "производительность критична." предполагает уход и с .NET и с BC++ и переход на нормальные компиляторы.

Comment: Попрошу без холиваров на тему .Net vs С++, производительности конкретных платформ и компиляторов. Для тех кто в танке: "производительность критична." - подразумевается отсутствие ощутимого увеличения времени выполнения по сравнению вызовом тех же методов в .Net Окружении

Comment: 1. COM. 2. http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=44349 Других способов не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд самый простой способ - это написание промежуточной dll на C++\CLI, который позволяет с одной стороны нормально экспортировать методы через `__declspec(dllexport)`, а с другой нормально вызывать методы из библиотек, которые написаны на C#.

Когда сам интересовался этим вопросом, то плагины для VS не работали корректно, по-моему, из-за кирилицы (может за пару лет стало лучше), а вручную декомпилировать библиотеку и вносить изменения в MSIL быстро надоело.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - просто экспортировать нужные функции из DLL с помощью библиотеки [UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports). Скачать ее и подключить к проекту можно через NuGet.

Инициализацию библиотеки можно проводить в статическом конструкторе. Или же можно воспользоваться паттернами ленивой инициализации.

Если нужно более сложное взаимодействие - можно использовать COM. Регистрировать интерфейсы и фабрики классов в реестре не обязательно - достаточно экспортировать функцию, которая вернет COM-интерфейс. Пример такого кода есть на сайте UnmanagedExports.